# T-SQL return results and continue processing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that I am hoping to speed up by returning the data early from the stored procedure and then allowing it to continue processing afterwards.

Basically right now I have something like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure_Name, sysname, ProcedureName> 
    @someargshere
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE lastAccessedTime = GETUTCDATE() WHERE based on someargs;
    SELECT some fields WHERE based on someargs;
END
```

I don't actually care about what lastAccessedTime is for the `SELECT` statement but the only way I have found to return a result set of rows is to do the `SELECT` at the end, because all the docs I've found have said `RETURN` only takes an integer expression. I would like to return results early so that I get the absolute fastest response time possible to my application so that it can continue processing while still having the server do the update. So I would like to do something like

```
SELECTT.....
RETURN results to app
UPDATE after connection has sent results
```

Is that possible or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to accomplish in the SP, but assuming you want to mark a set of rows with a new `lastAccessedTime` and then return data from those rows you might be able to improve performance by using an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause on the `UPDATE` to save data from the affected rows into a temporary table. A `SELECT` from the temporary table would return the results. Your current design, without adding a transaction, allows another user to update rows between the `UPDATE` and `SELECT`, something `OUTPUT` would preclude.

Answer (score 6):

NO, don't think you can do that cause it's a sequential processing. Moreover even you are able to do that then you will end up reading the old data and not the updated data actually; which is also known as `DIRTY READ`.

What you posted in first part is the right thing to do. Perform the `UPDATE` first and then `SELECT` the data and return to application. Your procedure will return only when the entire processing is over and not partially likewise you are saying (Or likewise happens in a multithreaded programming language).

Though you can separate the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in different procedure / adhoc query and based on your application programming language (if it's support multi threading); have two thread running where one will `SELECT` from table and another will perform `UPDATE` (if `C#` then you can use TPL; specifically `async - await`). Though you will have to set the `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` to `READ UNCOMMITTED` probably in that case.

Comment: _"separate the SELECT and UPDATE in different procedure / adhoc"_ - upvoted.

Comment: I'm ok with reading old data as what I'm reading is not what I'm updating